# Html5 elements not working in ie8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

Im trying to make webpage that i did in html5 work in ie8, but it looks all over the place.

it works in ie9+, chrome and firefox perfectly.

I tried adding html5.js in the head section before the css, but it still doesn't work

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

The webpage is here for you to test:

> https://vvpx.localtunnel.me

Comment: Try sticking it after your css is loaded but still in the head.

Comment: @cab i tried this but its still not working, thanks

Comment: Put it back to where it was and see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

You are on https: and the shim/shiv is http: so remove the http:

Comment: The poster said that it works on other browsers but not IE8...how could it work on other browsers??

Comment: Because all other browsers don't need it, it's between conditionals

Answer (score 0):

Check if IE8 supports the HTML5 elements that you're looking to implement using this link: [HTML5 Support](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/mybrowser/firefox-26/ie-11/ie-10/ie-9.html)

IE8 is old and buggy, and it definitely doesn't support most of the HTML5 elements (substitute IE9 in that comparison list with IE8).

Answer (score -1):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script>
      document.createElement('header');
      document.createElement('nav');
      document.createElement('section');
      document.createElement('article');
      document.createElement('aside');
      document.createElement('footer');
   </script>
<![endif]-->
```